FastAPIs event loop and Scrapy's Twisted thread don't play well together
I have a Scrapy spider that I trigger from a Rest API endpoint implemented in FastAPI. Scrapy has a provision to launch a spider from a Python script like so:
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from tundra.spiders.spiderfool import SpiderfoolSpider

def run_spiderfool(start_page=1, number_pages=2):

    process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())

    # Run the spider programmatically
    process.crawl(SpiderfoolSpider, start_page=start_page, number_pages=number_pages)
    process.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_spiderfool(1, 2)  # Example usage, include for each spider

This script "run_spider.py" is in the folder that has "scrapy.cfg". Here, SpiderfoolSpider is the class that implements the spider and start_page and number_pages are args passed. This script works perfect well as standalone: python3 run_spider.py.
Now I integrate it in my Rest API end-point:
@app.get("/api/trigger/spiderfool")
def trigger_spider(
    start_page: int = Query(1, ge=1),
    number_pages: int = Query(2, ge=1)
):
    try:
        logger.info(f"Starting spider with start_page={start_page}, number_pages={number_pages}")
        run_spiderfool(start_page=start_page, number_pages=number_pages)

        return {"message": f"Success! Triggered spider to crawl Motley Fool's transcripts collection from page {start_page} for {number_pages} pages!"}
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Failure! Triggered no spider! Err: {str(e)}")
        return {"error": "Failure! Triggered no spider!", "details": str(e)}

The spider only runs the 1st time it is triggered from the end-point, printing success message. Every subsequent time I trigger the endpoint, it fails and prints the failure message with empty string e. Looking into the logs, I see in the 1st (successful) run, an error message:
"ValueError: signal only works in main thread of the main interpreter"
I reckon this is because Scrapy or some libraries used by it, like twisted, rely on signals that only work in the main thread.
What I have tried:
I put asyncioreactor.install() from twisted's asyncioreactor in the FastAPI main and refactored the end-point into an async method like so:
@app.get("/api/trigger/spiderfool")
async def trigger_spider(
    start_page: int = Query(1, ge=1),
    number_pages: int = Query(2, ge=1)
):
    try:
        logger.info(f"Starting spider with start_page={start_page}, number_pages={number_pages}")
        asyncio.create_task(arun_spiderfool(start_page=start_page, number_pages=number_pages))
        return {"message": f"Success! Triggered spider to crawl Motley Fool's transcripts collection from page {start_page} for {number_pages} pages!"}
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Failure! Triggered no spider! Err: {str(e)}")
        return {"error": "Failure! Triggered no spider!", "details": str(e)}

The "run_spider.py" now has an async call to the spider like so:
async def arun_spiderfool(start_page=1, number_pages=2):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_in_executor(None, run_spiderfool, start_page, number_pages)

def run_spiderfool(start_page=1, number_pages=2):

    process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())

    # Run the spider programmatically
    process.crawl(SpiderfoolSpider, start_page=start_page, number_pages=number_pages)
    process.start()

This did not change the behavior of the code! Other things I tried patching the Scrapy thread with FastAPI event loop using nest_asyncio. These did not help.
I finally went the route of using subprocess module.
import subprocess

def run_spiderfool(start_page=1, number_pages=2):
    subprocess.Popen(['scrapy', 'crawl', 'spiderfool', 
                      f'-a', f'start_page={start_page}', 
                      f'-a', f'number_pages={number_pages}'])

This resolves the issue but has the side-effect that the end-point can only launch the spider and not track when it completes.
So are FastAPI's event loop and Scrapy's Twisted threading library incompatible?

While not an answer to your actual question, I'd recommend looking into using a task queue and workers to perform the spider task - the FastAPI part appends the task to the queue, and the workers do the actual work. You can use a websocket connection to receive updates in you frontend from the fastapi server, which in turn receives them from the worker (for example over a redis pubsub channel between the worker and fastapi). Having the scraper "inside" FastAPI means that you can end up with slow web requests because of the scrapers overloading your backend server (and potentional DoS attacks).

@MatsLindh That makes sense! Thank you for your excellent suggestion. I appreciate it.

Running CrawlerProcess.start() more than once in the same process was never going to work, which is unrelated to threading, Scrapy or event loops, only to the Twisted reactor which you were trying to stop and start again. If you don't like the subprocess solution you need to integrate the Twisted reactor into your event loop (somehow).

@wRAR can you say more? I tried @MatsLindh solution to run process in background from FastAPI trigger with Celery and Redis broker and I get raise error.ReactorNotRestartable() twisted.internet.error.ReactorNotRestartable after one run which seems in line with what you are saying.

@SunBee what else do you want to know?

I ended up taking up @MatsLindh suggestion and implementing FastAPI end-point that triggers a Scrapy spider to run as a background task using Celery to manage the task queue.
The Celery task is as follows:
from celery.app import Celery
import os
import subprocess

redis_url = os.getenv("REDIS_URL", "redis://localhost:6379")

celery_app = Celery(
    "scraper",
    broker = redis_url,
    backend = redis_url
)

@celery_app.task
def run_spiderfool_task(start_page=1, number_pages=2):
    try:
        # Run the Scrapy spider with arguments
        command = [
            "scrapy", "crawl", "spiderfool",             # spider name
            "-a", f"start_page={start_page}",             # custom argument for start_page
            "-a", f"number_pages={number_pages}"          # custom argument for number_pages
        ]
        
        # Execute the command
        process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        
        # Wait for the process to finish
        stdout, stderr = process.communicate()

        # Check if there are any errors
        if process.returncode != 0:
            print(f"Error: {stderr.decode('utf-8')}")
        else:
            print(f"Spider completed successfully! Output:\n{stdout.decode('utf-8')}")
    
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")


Celery uses a Redis broker and backend. The process.communicate() is blocking and ensures the crawler completes before exiting the function.
The FastAPI endpoints are as follows:
@app.post("/trigger/spiderfool")
def trigger_spider(
    start_page: int = Query(1, ge=1),
    number_pages: int = Query(2, ge=1)
):
    spiderfool_task = run_spiderfool_task.delay(start_page, number_pages)
    return {"job_id": spiderfool_task.id, "message": "Started spider!"}

@app.get("/status/{job_id}")
def get_status(job_id: str):
    job_info = AsyncResult(job_id)
    return {
        "job_id": job_info.id,
        "job_status": job_info.status,
        "job_result": job_info.result
    }

I dockerized the app to have three containers as follows:

FastAPI: Hosts the app that serves REST API endpoints.
Celery: Does the heavy-lifting, queuing requests and executing tasks in the background on a single worker.
Redis: Serves as broker and backend for Celery.

Now I can trigger spiders from FastAPI and monitor the job with the job id.
Thanks @MatsLindh @wRAR for inputs.
